# Tkinter Scrollbar in textWidget, howto

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a small texteditor in python. With `app` being my master i am trying to implement a textWidget, in which i want to place a functional scrollbar.

The problem i am facing is following:

- In order to have a textWidget to place my scrollbar in, i have to implement my textWidget first. But already as an argument in `Tk.Text` i need to place the `yscrollcommand` for my scrollbar. Which means that my textWidget will not know what my scrollbar is.

If i turn it around i am not able to create my scrollbar within the textWidget, because it is not yet created.

First example where my textWidget is created first

```
    # MENU BAR EXAMPLE
    menu_bar = Tk.Menu()
    # Set menu bar as menu for the app
    app.config(menu=menu_bar)
    # Fill menubar with "File" menu
    filemenu = Tk.Menu(app,menu_bar, tearoff=0)
    #filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File2", menu=filemenu)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

    # BUTTON EXAMPLE
    button = Tk.Button(app, text="Exit", command=quit)
    button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.X)

    # TEXT WIDGET

    textWidget = Tk.Text(textWidget, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    textWidget.pack(expand=True,fill=Tk.BOTH)

    # SCROLLBAR

    scrollbar=Tk.Scrollbar(textWidget)
    scrollbar.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill= Tk.Y)
    scrollbar.config(command=textWidget.yview)

    #Start the main event loop (i.e. run the tkinter program)
    app.mainloop()


    ######################################################
```

Second example where scrollbar is created first

```
# MENU BAR EXAMPLE
menu_bar = Tk.Menu()
# Set menu bar as menu for the app
app.config(menu=menu_bar)
# Fill menubar with "File" menu
filemenu = Tk.Menu(app,menu_bar, tearoff=0)
#filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File2", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

# BUTTON EXAMPLE
button = Tk.Button(app, text="Exit", command=quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.X)

# SCROLLBAR
scrollbar=Tk.Scrollbar(textWidget)
scrollbar.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill= Tk.Y)
scrollbar.config(command=textWidget.yview)

# TEXT WIDGET

textWidget = Tk.Text(textWidget, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) 
textWidget.pack(expand=True,fill=Tk.BOTH)
```

And this is how i had to do to make it work. But it feelsBadMan if i have to create a textWidget, create a scrollbar and then create a textWidget again.

```
    # MENU BAR EXAMPLE
menu_bar = Tk.Menu()
# Set menu bar as menu for the app
app.config(menu=menu_bar)
# Fill menubar with "File" menu
filemenu = Tk.Menu(app,menu_bar, tearoff=0)
#filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File2", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

# BUTTON EXAMPLE
button = Tk.Button(app, text="Exit", command=quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.X)

# TEXT WIDGET

textWidget = Tk.Text(app)
textWidget.pack(expand=True,fill=Tk.BOTH)

# SCROLLBAR

scrollbar=Tk.Scrollbar(textWidget)
scrollbar.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT, fill= Tk.Y)

textWidget = Tk.Text(textWidget, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) # <--- Creating textWidget again

#textWidget.pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill=Tk.BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=textWidget.yview)
textWidget.pack(expand=True,fill=Tk.BOTH)


# Start the main event loop (i.e. run the tkinter program)
app.mainloop()
```

Any ideas? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes three steps:

1. create the text widget
2. create the scrollbar, and link it to the text widget
3. link the text widget to the scrollbar

You can reverse the order if you want: create the scrollbar, then the text, then configure the scrollbar. Also, the scrollbar should *not* be placed inside the text widget. The text widget and the scrollbar typically share the same parent.

Example:

```
textWidget = Tk.Text(app)
scrollbar = Tk.Scrollbar(app, command=textWidget.yview)
textWidget.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. The problem and why i ended up packing my scrollbar in the textWidget is because if i dont, i end up with a scrollbar interface in the bottom off the app, and the textwidget only stretches to the top of the scrollbars interface.

Comment: EDIT.
 If the scrollbar is created first and then the textWidget, it will work.
The scrollbar will take place and strecth itself in the app, and the textWidget will then take place an stretch itself on the rest of the app